# Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>) Eclipse and Visual Studio Code NOK. Maven and IntellJ OK

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

If I edit my Java project in Eclipse or Visual Studio Code the embedded Java compiler complains about this code:

```
List<? extends TableField<?, ?>> pkFields = pkTable.getPrimaryKey().getFields();
pkFields.stream().map(record::get).forEach(pkValuesAsString::append);
```

> Cannot infer type argument(s) for  map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)

When I build the project with Maven or edit it in IntelliJ everything is fine.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio Code and Eclipse?

Comment: `Eclipse` uses `ecj` compiler, I assume `VCS` has some of it's own too? `maven` uses whatever you configured (most probably `javac`). You should mainly trust `javac`...  Either way don't use `forEach` like that : `String pkValuesAsString  = pkFields.stream().map(record::get).collect(Collectors.joining())`

Comment: Thanks. But this does not answer my question.

Comment: first of all - you do not have a question to begin with, I inferred it. Second, the answer would be : `Eclipse` and `VSC` both have bugs (would not be anything new about that).

Comment: Fair enough. I added the question.

Comment: yes, this is most probably a bug. In general, in my experience, I have seen quite a few bugs like this in `Eclipse ecj`, it might have to do with the fact that you are using a somehow old version too.

Comment: I'm using Spring Tool Suite 4.7 this is based on Eclipse JDT 3.18 and Eclipse Platform 4.16 so pretty new I think

Comment: I see. Sorry, I don't use Eclipse at all so difficult for me to weight in, but it seems you might want to open a defect against their database.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to do that. Thanks

Comment: VSC's language server uses ECJ under the covers, so it's the sort of thing that would show up in both.

Comment: @nitind Interesting! Thank you